# Java - Spring and Mockito - Mocking a constructor parameter that is not a field in class?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, junit-runner

I have the following `Spring` component that I am trying to unit test:

```
@Component
public class OrderService {

    private final DatabaseConnection dbConnection;
    private final String collectionName;

    @Autowired
    public OrderService(
            DatabaseConnection dbConnection,
            DatabaseConfig databaseConfig) {

        this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
        this.collectionName = databaseConfig.getCollectionName();
    }
    
    //methods etc...
    
    }
```

The `DatabaseConfig` class is as follows:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "database")
@ConstructorBinding
public class DatabaseConfig {

    //methods etc...
}
```

I am trying to inject mocks in my `OrderService` class as follows:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class OrderServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    OrderService orderService;

    @Mock
    DatabaseConnection dbConnection; // working as expected
    @Mock
    DatabaseConfig databaseConfig; // giving null pointer
    @Mock
    DatabaseCollectionConfig databaseCollectionConfig;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

        when(databaseConfig.getCollections()).thenReturn(databaseCollectionConfig);
        when(databaseCollectionConfig.getCollectionName()).thenReturn("myCollection");

    }
```

When I run my test class I get:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InjectMocksException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'OrderService' of type 'class com.my.package.OrderService'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : null
```

The issue is that in the `OrderService` constructor when I debug this line is coming as null:

```
 this.collectionName = databaseConfig.getCollectionName();
```

How can I correctly mock `databaseConfig.getCollectionName()` to solve the null issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use @InjectMock annotation because you are using constructor based injection in your service class. Please rewrite your test case like this and try again.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class OrderServiceTest {

    OrderService orderService;

    @Mock
    DatabaseConnection dbConnection; // working as expected
    @Mock
    DatabaseConfig databaseConfig; // giving null pointer
    @Mock
    DatabaseCollectionConfig databaseCollectionConfig;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup(){
   when(databaseConfig.getCollections()).thenReturn(databaseCollectionConfig);

when(databaseCollectionConfig.getCollectionName()).thenReturn("myCollection");

   orderService = new OrderService(dbConnection, databaseConfig);

       
       

    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a mock for that method and create an object instance instead of using the `InjectMocks` annotation.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class OrderServiceTest {

    OrderService orderService;

    @Mock
    DatabaseConnection dbConnection; // working as expected
    @Mock
    DatabaseConfig databaseConfig; // giving null pointer
    @Mock
    DatabaseCollectionConfig databaseCollectionConfig;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
  
        (...)
  
        when(databaseConfig.getCollections()).thenReturn(databaseCollectionConfig);
        when(databaseCollectionConfig.getCollectionName()).thenReturn("myCollection");
        orderService = new OrderService(dbConnection, databaseConfig);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mock *behavior*, not *values*. An `@ConfigurationProperties` class is just a container for data; it doesn't (generally speaking) *do* anything. Create a real one with `new` using your test values (e.g., `setCollections(testDatabaseCollectionConfig)`).